# How to divide vector into quintiles

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

My question is not so much about code, it's more of an algorithm problem. I am trying to think of a way to divide a vector of doubles into "quintiles" i.e. 5 parts. I then need to find the average of each individual part. The vector can have any number of data points. Does anyone have an idea of how to go about determining what the beginning and end index would be for each quintile? If anyone would like to suggest code, the language I am working with is C++. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile explains convention of split.

Comment: else, following bounds (`0`, `size / 5`, `2 * size / 5`, `3 * size / 5`, `4 * size / 5`, `size`) are good approximation.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to come up with a solution based on the article you shared.

Comment: If you would like to share your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer